# ACCESS/VBA: can't get Dcount to work correctly

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

here is a portion of code I'm using to enable/disable a button (which allows to create a new revision) depending on the result.

If the dcount returns 0, it means the next revision doesn't exist yet (and thus can be created)
if the dcount returns 1, it means the next revision already exists (and thus the button will be disabled)

```
DCount("index_rit", "t_données_rit", "[RITn°]=" & Me.RITn°.Value & " AND [Revision]=" & Me.Revision.Value + 1)
```

My problem is that for some reason, even if a record corresponds to the values entered in the dcount, it still returns 0.

I tried both with ant without the [] for the fields.
I also tried using * instead of index_rit...

What did I get wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it.
it was a format problem: 
RITn° is of the form xx-xx, so I had to put it like this:

```
"[RITn°]='" & Me.RITn°.Value & "' AND [Revision]=" & Me.Revision.Value + 1)
```

(added the single quotes)

Comment: The .Value property is redundant, as it's the default property. However, it can be useful in cases where you're passing the value to a function/subroutine with parameters defined ByRef (i.e., using .Value will pass ByVal, instead, although so will surrounding the control reference with parens to force evaluation before it's passed to the function/sub).

Answer (score -1):

First thing is that the DCount (and other ‘D’ functions) are generally considered to be a bit of a performance drag. Try replacing it with this quick function. You just pass it a query and it will return the record count

```
Private Function GetRecordCount(strSearch as String) as Long
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim RecCount As Long

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

With rst
   .ActiveConnection = CodeProject.Connection
   .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
   .LockType = adLockReadOnly
   .Source = strSearch
   .Open Options:=adCmdText
   if .EOF = true then
        RecCount=0
   else
        RecCount=.Collect(0)
   End If

   .Close
End With

GetRecordCount = RecCount

Set rst = Nothing

End Function
```

This uses ADO but could/should use DAO if you are just using access tables but that is another question for another time!

Comment: ADO is not a good idea in Access. Domain Aggregate functions are very useful indeed, unless your database is so large that you should probably be considering another back-end. Access is used a lot by people other than programmers and options that allow controls to be filled without any coding are an advantage.

Comment: I know that ADO is not the best thing to use if you are dealing with just JET tables hence the last sentence in my answer saying this could/should use DAO. All my JET based programs use DAO it is only if I am using other data sources that I will use ADO. It is very useful that access has these domain functions, hell I’m guilty of using them sometimes but I was just trying to make the OP aware that they are a potential trouble area if used on large tables

Comment: I knew about this option but it requires a lot more lines.  
I wanted to keep the code as simple and short as possible (performance is not an issue here and there isn't that much records)  
Thanks for showing the "other way" though :)

Comment: @Kevin Ross, Agreed, ADO is very useful with other data sources, or even outside of Access with Jet (shh! :) )

Comment: Opening a cursor when you just need the record count can't be a solution. Just do a "SELECT COUNT(..." and fetch the one values that comes as a result.

Comment: Yes of course you should use the aggregate functions to return only the one record, This was (quickly) taken from another bit of code that did need to open each record. I have tweaked it slightly. At some point I will post a DAO example but I have some real work to get on with for now!

Comment: Back in the days of A97, the domain aggregate functions were slow on linked tables, so many of us used custom replacement functions structured like what you've posted (though using DAO, of course). But A2000 fixed the problem and so I don't think there's going to be any performance benefit to coding your own.